# Scipy curve_fit returning correct parameters but infinite covariance matrix

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am testing the `scipy.optimize` function `curve_fit()`. I am testing on a Quadratic function, and I have assigned the x and y data manually for this question. I do get the expected answer for the values of my parameters for *basically* every guess I put in. However, I noticed that for guesses of the first parameter not close to 0 (particularly, after 1), I get a Covariance Matrix full of infinity. I am not sure why such a simple test is failing.

```
# python version: 3.9.7
# using a venv
# numpy version: 1.23.2
# scipy version: 1.9.0
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# data taken from a quadratic function of: y = 3*x**2 + 2
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], dtype=np.float64)
y = np.array([2, 5, 14, 29, 50, 77, 110, 149, 194, 245, 302], dtype=np.float64)

# quadratic function
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x**2 + b * x + c

# test to reproduce success case - notice that we have success when changing the first value upto a value of 1.0
success = [0, 0, 0]
# test to reproduce failure case
failure = [4, 0, 0]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=failure)  # change p0 to success or failure

print(popt)  # expected answer is [3, 0, 2]
print(pcov)  # covariance matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

The covariance matrix is really only useful (and in general, can only be calculated) when each and every variable is optimized. That generally means the variable is moved away from its initial value and in a way so that the dependence of the fit quality (typically, chi-square) from changing the value of this variable can be determined.

It also turns out that if initial guesses are bad, the solution may not be found -- and some variables may not actually be moved from their initial values.  I think that is what is happening for you.

An initial value of "0" is particularly troublesome, as the fit really does not know "how zero" that is.  Is that "magnitude less than 1e-16"  or "magnitude less than 1"?   Even using initial values of `[4, 0.01, 0.01]` would get to a good solution.

An additional potential problem is that your "data" is exactly given by the model function and values.  At "the right solution", the residual will be really very very close to zero, and converting the Jacobian matrix of derivatives (of misfit with respect to variables) to covariance can be numerically unstable.  That would be very unlikely with real data, but you may want to add a small amount of noise to the data being modeled.

Comment: Your last paragraph likely explains the problem in this case. Changing 302 to 302.1 "fixes" the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're expecting a different covariance matrix. The documentation says:

> If the Jacobian matrix at the solution doesn’t have a full rank, then ‘lm’ method returns a matrix filled with np.inf

As far as I understand the Jacobian matrix is estimated during the optimization, and depending on what initialization you use the above case might happen. Note that the result of `popt` still converges!